# jQuery .load() with data argument does not post

Tags: jquery, ajax

In documentation it says, that when using `load()` with second (data) argument, the data will be post. But it does not work.

```
$('#open').load('ajax/open_map.php',$('.frm_open').serialize());
```

The request made is:

```
GET /ajax/open_map.php?filter_name=blahblah&filter_id=1 HTTP/1.1
```

How do I force it to POST and not GET?

Comment: Did you check the API? `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.` http://api.jquery.com/load/. `serialize()` returns a string.

Comment: any way to serialize form to object?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#open').load('ajax/open_map.php',{data:$('.frm_open').serializeArray()});
```

You should post like object

Comment: oh, this will post one string contained in `data` ... but, yes it works as post... so I need to serialize form manually...

Comment: Why can not you use .serializeArray() refer: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ good to make it posted as array object, then at server side you can handle it using post method

Comment: Because right answer is in comment? :) Edit your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery load is simply equivalent to $.get so use $.post . http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$.get(url, data, success)
```

Comment: It is not true, because $.post does not interpretate scripts inside query result. And I need POST, not GET.